# Shopify output line items as json values

Tags: shopify, liquid, checkout

I am trying to amend our tracking code for Shopify to output the items in the order, but it's giving me issues as not returning what i want. Any ideas please. It's var pr = values that are not working. The rest is fine and outputs what we need:

```
<!-- Onefeed Tracking -->

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     var of_ssid = 'xxxx';
     var cs = '{{ total_price | money_without_currency }}';
     var oi = '{{ order_number }}';
     var it = '{{ line_item.quantity }}';
     var pr = '{% assign items = line_item.product_id | split: "," | parse_json %}
{{ items[forloop.index] }}';
     var nc = '';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://tracking.onefeed.co.uk/t.js"></script>
<noscript>
    <img border="0" src="https://tracking.onefeed.co.uk/ProcessProductCheckout.ashx?of_ssid=xxxx&cs={{ total_price | money_without_currency }}&it={{ line_item.quantity }}&oi={{ order_number }}&nc=&pr={% assign items = line_item.product_id | split: "," | parse_json %}
{{ items[forloop.index] }}" />
</noscript>

<!-- /Onefeed Tracking -->
```

Comment: What are you expecting to get in the `pr` variable?  Your syntax there isn't clear as to what you want to collect.  Also - I see a reference to a `forloop.index` - is this located inside a `for` loop?

Comment: Assuming that `{{ line_item.quanttiy }}` is giving the correct info, if you want the entire line_item's JSON data you can use `{{ line_item | json }}`.

Comment: I need simply the item IDs to be looped through which are comma separated. So if someone had 4 items in their order i want to loop through all items to pass the data as a json like: '1234,5678,91011,12131'. I may have got the syntax wrong for the loop part. I'm not too au fait with liquid like this. The item.quantity is giving me the correct value here, just need the item IDs now.

Comment: Have you tried anything like `{{ order.line_items | map: 'id' | join: ',' | json }}`?  The `map` filter is extremely useful for getting an array without needing to set up a loop. `Join` will then turn that array into a string, and `json` will output everything as a javascript-legal variable (which includes wrapping the value with quotes and escaping any special characters - it's an all-round awesome filter whenever translating Liquid variables to Javascript -but I digress...)